# Question posted in facebook.stackoverflow.com not appearing in site search

Tags: support, status-bydesign, search

I posted this question to facebook.stackoverflow.com yesterday: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8043814/changing-open-graph-image-tag-based-on-blog-post-item, but it does not appear in the site level search. I searched both by its title and by copy and pasting the bulk of its body. It has been indexed by google. Can anyone explain why it doesn't appear in the site level search results?

Comment: Also the question is not appearing on my user profile page:
http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/405484/tks

Comment: When I look it's on page 3 (I use 50 per page). It's also in your profile when sorted by recent.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize the questions on the user profile are paginated. My mistake.  It appears for me if I search the title as a literal string, "Changing open graph image tag based on blog post item" but not if there are no quotes, which seems odd given its recency, no down votes, and literal match. Even if it appeared on page 3 thats pretty rough for someone trying to organically find the post. Likewise when I search for any of the body text without quotes. Thoughts?

Comment: This is a problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: Proper title full search]

You don't get this if you don't do a literal search (with quotation marks as shown above) because [image](/questions/tagged/image) is one of the top tags on Stack Overflow. As such, when it shows up as a term in a search, it is automatically converted into a tag search with that tag. This is so that if someone searches for a ludicrously common thing (like, say, c# or java), we just point them at the tag search for that.

As such, if you want to search for a term that happens to be a common tag, you need to escape it. You can use `"`, or `+`, or if you know it's in a title you could even use `title:`. More options are shown on the [Search Help](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

[image: Result of a non-literal search]

Your question doesn't have [image](/questions/tagged/image), so it will not show up. The above image demonstrates the auto-tag-search functionality for the particular title string.